# Installing "unknown" packages to tex-live

Tags: packages, installing, texlive

I had quite some problems with `tlmgr` and a faulty TeX Live installation on Linux but now, everything works okay, I guess. Anyhow, on my Mac I am using the package [mcode from mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package), which I want to install on my Linux machine as well. The [package install manual on tug.org](https://www.tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html) however tells me

> If you accept scheme-full, and you still didn't get the material you were expecting [...] the package may not be available under a free software license, in which case it cannot be included in TeX Live.

Do I simply put the `.sty`-file to `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/` or `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/` ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: To tell your TeX distribution that you installed a new package, you may need to `texhash` in the command line.

Comment: add it to the `texmf-local` folder your installing have made for you. Remember to use a TDS folder structure and and the *binary person* notes, remember to run `texhash`. Depending on how you installed TL14 you may need `sudo`

Comment: BTW: you can ask for the location of the `-local` folder via `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL`